# Send command line args while opening a file

Tags: c, cocoa, command-line

I have generated a pdf file external to my app, and once that is complete, I want to open my app and pass it the appropriate file path for use.  I've looked at the [Cocoa Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html), but I'm not sure if this is what I need.  All I really want is to pass the path of the pdf as an argument via the command line.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: Surely you mean `/Applications/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp`?  If you use `open` then just reference the `.app` bundle, and pass the parameters as per my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to run it from a shell script of some sort?  If so, you should be able to use the `open` command ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html)) to start it:

```
$ open /Applications/MyApp.app --args /path/to/file.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, that sounds like what I need.  How do I then access that path within xcode for use in my application?  Is it passed into the `char *argv[]` of the main function?  And if it is, how do I get it to the App delegate considering the only line in my main function is `return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);`

Comment: @Katie I thought support for passing the arguments (and automatically opening the windows) was already provided by the framework.  Is your app a document-based app?

Comment: My app currently is not a document-based app, just a regular cocoa application.  I don't need to handle multiple documents, basically just need to take the document provided as the argument, get some information from various servers, and send that document to a device.  Is there a way to use `NSProcessInfo` to get the arguments?  Currently after making my .app file, when I try to print the arguments from `NSArray *args = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, nothing seems to appear.

Comment: @Katie I don't know I'm afraid; the docs for `NSProcessInfo` seem to indicate that *should* work fine.